# How to set image from external server to kv file

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

My code works perfectly for image saved in same directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<MenuScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            on_press: root.val1()
            Image:
                source: "myimage.PNG"
                size: self.parent.width, self.parent.height
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False

''')

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def val1(self):
        print "i am executed"

sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

What changes should be made in this code if i want to take image from external source ie

```
Image:
    source: "http://example.com/myimage.jpg"
```

Obviously this does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `AsyncImage` instead. From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#asynchronous-loading):

> To load an image asynchronously (for example from an external
>   webserver), use the AsyncImage subclass:
>
> ```
> aimg = AsyncImage(source='http://mywebsite.com/logo.png')
> ```
>
> This can be useful as it prevents your application from waiting until
>   the image is loaded. If you want to display large images or retrieve
>   them from URL’s, using AsyncImage will allow these resources to be
>   retrieved on a background thread without blocking your application.

Comment: I checked this, the example does not have .kv file. I have no idea where to put this code.

Comment: Just replace `Image` in your .kv code with `AsyncImage`.

Comment: Thanks @Nykakin, it worked. By the way, what will happen if someone uses this code without wifi or mobile data. I mean, do i need to handle this case or kivy will handle.

Comment: In that case the default spinning image of loader will be used. You can change it using `Loader.loading_image = "default_image.png"`.